# Can you make Apple TV (4th generation) a server? Or get commands from a web server?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, webserver, apple-tv

I working on a side project with Apple TV (4th generation) and smartphones. I want to control the Apple TV content from a smartphone (for now from an iPhone) and from the Siri remote as well.

My first thought was to develop an iPhone app and pair the phone and Apple TV with bluetooth. The Apple TV listens for changes made from the app. That works great, but the downside is the time it takes to install the app, and pair it with the TV.

A better way might be to have a webpage that is accessed from the browser in the phone. Once the user navigates the webpages, the content changes in the Apple TV accordingly.

**Which comes to my question: Can the server of this website be the Apple TV itself? Can I make the Apple TV listen (or get commands) from a web-server?**

I would appreciate an feedback or advice. If you think this can be done and you know resources where I can learn more on how to do it, please share them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sever part might be possible to build, but you will not be able to control any other app in the Apple TV, thus you will also have to  build your own video, music player and what not.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Does this require for the Apple TV to be jailbreak? Why would the other apps not work anymore?

Comment: Well other apps would work, but since all iOS app are sandboxed you will not be able to control, lets say, the Netflix app. May when a Jailbreak will be available you might be able to do it.

Comment: I don't want to control the other apps with my phone, or from the web page I am talking about. I want to control only my app this way. The other apps should stay like they are, controlled from the Siri remote only.

Comment: Yes that is possible, you need to embed some webserver code in your app. Like: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html